# Nativescript get value of textfield

Tags: nativescript

In NativeScript, how can I get the value of a textfield using JavaScript (not TypeScript/Angular)?

XML:

I've tried various combinations of "getViewByID()" but nothing is working (perhaps I didn't "require" right libraries?).  Not looking to do 2-way binding; just get the value (print to the console).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as a reminder, it's usually a good idea to share some code with your question to show what you have already tried.
In this example you could have shared some xml markup for instance.
Anyways to get the value of a textfield you would have something like this.

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var textfield= view.getViewById(page, "textfieldID");
}
```

After this you should be able to do :

```
var text = textField.text;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  (I tried to add in the XML, but I guess it didn't work because I didn't put it in the proper code block)